# Groundhog Day bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

In the past, when I got a message, the message box lit up, and after I read the message, the box remained unlit until the next message.

Now the light reappears after a while, same already read message. And then again. Just like Groundhog Day, but less entertaining.

I believe that the problem first occurred after the recent outage.

Comment: It seems that similar problems happened in the past: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13873/persistent-comment

Comment: It seems to be different. I see that the upvote light is also affected, it keeps being lit, and does not reset. The phenomenon affects computers that use two different operating systems. A fix would be nice.

Comment: This may be system-wide, as there's a similar complaint at MO: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1855/notification-doesnt-go-away

Comment: Also recent post at meta.SE: [reputation notification shows up again after refresh](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238155/reputation-notification-shows-up-again-after-refresh)

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same bug: Red Notification about the same message on ten consecutive screens. And none of those due to hitting "Back" on the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had problems with a datacenter test that left our caching layer in a partially broken state.

All issues should now be resolved.

See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away